# Getting negative (inverted) image in Pytorch

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, torchvision

I want to get the negative of an image straight from the data loader and feed it as a tensor. Are there any libraries that I can use? I have tried torch `transforms` and didn't find any.

[image]

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/negative-of-an-image-using-pytorch-transforms/87059/3?u=iacob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 0.9, you can use `torchvision.transforms.functional.invert()` from the [torchvision transforms](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html) library.

Answer (score 4):

Don't struggle a lot just use `255-image` it will give you a negative image...Try it

Comment: this has to be done for each channel, right?

Comment: If you need any constimize you need to slice the array